# Glue Records, Bind9 and Ubuntu 11.10 - DNS Server not Responding?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, domains, glue-record

I'm attempting to create a DNS server to serve copies of a zone for 'example.com'.

**Preamble:**

The current setup includes:

- Ubuntu 11.10
- Bind9
- Apache 2

I have created Glue records at the registrar level, that resemble:

1. ns1.example.com A x.x.x.x
2. ns2.example.com A x.x.x.x

UFW has an exception for port 53.

**The Problem**

After installing Bind9, I have configured named.conf.local, named.conf.options (using Google DNS as my forwarders) and created a zone file (db.example.com) for my domain.

Upon testing my configuration via IntoDNS, no A record seems to be appearing, and I receive a slew of errors, including:

> ERROR: One or more of your nameservers did not respond:
>   The ones that did not respond are:
>   x.x.x.x

The above error seems to be a recurring issue, even indicated via a tracert provided by Network Tools:

> DNS server returned an error: Name server failed

**Requesting a Resolution**

So, what am I doing wrong? Why aren't my provided nameservers reachable?

I've followed numerous guides with no avail, any suggestions, resources or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

can you show that your named instance is listening on the external interfaces like so;

```
[root@someserver ~]# netstat -lnp | grep ":53 "
tcp        0      0 123.123.123.213:53       0.0.0.0:*       LISTEN      27989/named
udp        0      0 123.123.123.123:53       0.0.0.0:*                   27989/named
```

also that you are able to query the local nameserver using dig (from bind-utils package);

```
# dig @localhost example.com

; <<>> DiG 9.3.6-P1-RedHat-9.3.6-20.P1.el5 <<>> @localhost example.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options:  printcmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 35676
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 2, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;example.com.                   IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
example.com.            172800  IN      A       192.0.43.10

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
example.com.            172800  IN      NS      b.iana-servers.net.
example.com.            172800  IN      NS      a.iana-servers.net.

;; Query time: 17 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Sat May 26 03:45:20 2012
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 93
```

(i am not familiar with UFW) 
but the docs indicate that something like this should dump your running firewall;

```
# sudo ufw status verbose

Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
80/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
```

Comment: well if that ip is accurate, then your nameserver is up and available, because I can query it. Whats the domain name?

Comment: Hi Tom,

See [link](http://pastebin.com/pXfDT56C) for listening instances.

See [link](http://pastebin.com/H4yZ05VS) for dig responses.

See [link](http://pastebin.com/7ZZ4fuKX) for the db zone file.

See [link](http://pastebin.com/LYX2gYei) for the UFW status.

Hope this helps, thank's for the response!

Comment: the problem seems to be in the zone configuration because you would expect the dig to have an answer field, but its returning SERVFAIL, id: 4530

Comment: try to run the following command as root on the nameserver `named-checkconf /etc/named.conf
`

Comment: Running: named-checkconf /etc/named.conf, produces:

`root@xen:/etc/bind# named-checkconf /etc/named.conf
none:0: open: /etc/named.conf: file not found`

I didn't believe named.conf had to be in /etc/, I currently have it in /etc/bind/named.conf? 

/etc/bind/named.conf currently serves as a controller, it includes named.conf.local which includes the zone definition(s).

Comment: try `named-checkconf` alone, to see if its finding your `named.conf` automatically, and then try `named-checkconf /etc/bind/named.conf` to test your file syntax

Comment: Strange, it produces no results? As in, nothing appears?

Comment: thats the good sign.

Comment: basically if the zone was not configured locally, I would expect `dig @localhost xxxyyyzzz.com` to produce `NXDOMAIN` in the response, however as its producing `SERVFAIL` then config has loaded but has an error

Comment: try temporarily setting `recursion yes` in your `named.conf` like so; `options {
        directory "/etc";
        pid-file "/var/run/named/named.pid";`
        recursion yes;
        };

Answer (score 1):

Assumming that tcp/udp connectivity to port 53 on the server is not blocked...

The default BIND named.conf is for a DNS to work "as a caching only nameserver (as a localhost DNS resolver only)"

To turn that into a public DNS server, you may apply some of these according to your needs:

- list on any ip, by default it only listens in localhost
- allow-query from any
- recursion no, transfer none

.

```
...

options {
        listen-on port 53 { any; };
        listen-on-v6 port 53 { any; };
        directory       "/var/named";
        dump-file       "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
        statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
        memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
        allow-query     { any; };
        recursion no;
        allow-transfer { none; };

        dnssec-enable yes;
        dnssec-validation auto;

        auth-nxdomain no; # conform to RFC1035

        /* Path to ISC DLV key */
        bindkeys-file "/etc/named.iscdlv.key";

        managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";
};


...

include "/etc/named/named.conf.local";
```